# SpringBoot @OneToMany and How it Works

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have two entities, User and Product. A user contains a set of Product and is linked to the product table using @OneToMany. If I were to insert a new product, does Spring automatically update the user table to reflect the change or should I update the user table accordingly myself?

Answer (score 1):

If the relation is modeled correctly, the `User` table will not need any changes since the `Product` table has the PK field in it.

However, if you fetched it before the update, the entity `User` does not get updated automatically. There, you either have to fetch it again from the Repository or update the collection manually.

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Product> products;
}

public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @NotNull
    private User user;
}
```

This is a simple OneToMany mapping, where `Product` owns the relation. It holds a reference to the `User` table. To add another Product to the user, you create a new `Product`, where the `Product.user` field is set, and save it via the repository. The new row in the database will contain the correct user id, but the user referenced in the new Product, will not automatically have it in it's collection until you either fetch the user new or add the new product manually.